# Downloading large attachments from GeoNetwork

Tags: geonetwork, tomcat, jetty

I'm not able to download any attachment which is larger than 1GB, I'm getting the following error

```
<apiError>
<code>runtime_exception</code>
<description>Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Required array size too large</description>
<message>NestedServletException</message>
</apiError>
```

Our catalogue should allow downloads for large files (up to 10GB). Is there a possible way to download large attachments. I'm running GeoNetwork with Jetty server, also the same happened when using Tomcat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to confirm you allocated enough memory to your Java running Jetty/Tomcat hence your Geonetwork or add more memory to your server if not enough. It's not the definitive solution as the issue is known and has been resolved only recently (12 days at time of writing) with streaming content e.g https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/5449. I don't know which release of Geonetwork will land with the improved feature.